# AssertionError: only tensorflow v1 is supported

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have installed tensorflow by pip install. And when i run the application i have this arrow. What  I should do?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\1\Desktop\PathPlanning-main\Supervisor\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    assert str(tf.__version__).startswith('1.'), "only tensorflow v1 is supported"
AssertionError: only tensorflow v1 is supported
```

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'  # or any {'0', '1', '2'}
import tensorflow as tf
assert str(tf.__version__).startswith('1.'), "only tensorflow v1 is supported"
```

Ihave searched the internet about this problem but i didnt find

Comment: If you want to add more information to your question, please [edit] it rather than using comments or answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, from the error I'd imagine you've installed Tensorflow 2 and "the application" requires Tensorflow 1.x, as the error says.

You could do `pip install 'tensorflow<2.0'` to install the latest 1.x version available – however if "the application" has a `requirements.txt` file or similar, you should probably install the versions specified there.

Comment: pip install 'tensorflow<2.0'
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow<2.0 (from versions: 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.6.0rc0, 2.6.0rc1, 2.6.0rc2, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.6.4, 2.6.5, 2.7.0rc0, 2.7.0rc1, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.7.2
, 2.7.3, 2.7.4, 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.3, 2.10.0rc0, 2.10.0rc1, 2.10.0rc2, 2.10.0rc3, 2.10.0, 2.10.1, 2.11.0rc0, 2.11.0rc1, 2.11.0rc2, 2.11.0)    
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow<2.0

Comment: Right – the last Tensorflow 1.15 version available for Windows is for 64-bit Python 3.6, which I'd imagine you're not using. I wouldn't recommend downgrading to Python 3.6 either, because it's no longer supported.

Comment: Yep, unless you have a fairly specific use case (typically, that would be something like academic research) you should find something more modern. If you do, welp, prepare for a major headache with dependencies...

Answer (score 0):

- The error you are encountering is due to the code expecting a version
  1.x release of TensorFlow, but a different version is being used.
- To fix the error, you can either install a version 1.x release of
  TensorFlow or update the code to support the version of TensorFlow
  that you are currently using.
- You can check the version of TensorFlow that you are using by running

  `import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)`
- You can install a specific version of TensorFlow using `pip install    tensorflow==X.X`, where X.X is the version number you want to install.